# getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl not redirecting after payment process

Tags: php, magento, redirect, payment-gateway

I'm implementing a payment method in Magento and at the end of my payment process, I've included the getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl method.

```
public function authorize(Varien_Object $payment, $amount) {
    if ($amount <= 0) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('paygate')->__('Invalid amount for authorization.'));
    }
    $this->_auth_credentials[0] = Mage::getStoreConfig($this->_formDataInfo . 'username');
    $this->_auth_credentials[1] = Mage::getStoreConfig($this->_formDataInfo . 'vpnpwd');
    //The following _place method builds a request and returns the response from the payment gateway
    $this->_place($payment, $amount, $this->_auth_credentials);

    return $this;
}

public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() {
    Mage::Log('Returning Redirect URL:: ' . Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getLocalRedirect());
    return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getLocalRedirect();
}
```

The URL is set via a session upon a successful return of data from the payment service provider. I'm not calling this method anywhere, it's being called automatically as per the normal payment procedure.

The log displays the correct URL `Returning Redirect URL:: /payment/index/redirect` but then the process ends here without further redirection.

I've tried hardcoding the URL as a test, but it doesn't appear to work.

I'm not getting any errors or exceptions, just no redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution.

During this process I link off to a number of different custom classes; to handle the reporting of responses and building of the initial payment object to be sent to the payment gateway.

In a couple of these methods I found I was printing/logging some variables. Removing these fixed my issue!

It seems that printing/logging in this way can interrupt the process of redirection.

Normally this would tell me that the "headers have already been sent", but there was no error reporting at all, so it was difficult to debug.